# How to add button click event inside a literal on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Here is a my client side code (.aspx)

```
<asp:Literal ID="litFeatures" runat="server" />
```

Server side code:

```
sb.AppendLine("<form action=""/account/payment/"" method=""get"" id=""expert-order-form"">")

sb.AppendFormat("<p class=""dot-separated acenter"" style=""padding-top:20px;margin-top:5px;""><button type=""submit"" id=""button1""class=""btn"" value=""checkout"" onclick=""btn"">Register</button></p>")
```

This button currently redirects to action given in form. Instead of redirection I want to run a function.

How do I use the click event for this button? Where do I put the function?

Comment: You can't. The button is being generated on the client side and server doesn't know anything about them, so it can't handle them. Why do you do it like this in the first place? Doesn't really make much sense as is. Instead of literal control you try to replace with a string, use custom controls.

Comment: So I am actually working on code written by someone else. This literal contains a lot of dynamic stuff which is why I cant really replace it. I just need a way to write a function for button click event

Comment: currently it is inside a form tag. ie  `sb.AppendLine("<form action=""/account/abc/"" method=""get"" id=""order-form"">")` so the button works on this action. So instead of redirecting to /account/abc. I want to run a function.

Comment: That's how forms in html work... You can use ajax to communicate with your server, but not sure if it's the best way...

Answer (score 0):

case function is javascript:
    <button ... onClick="yourfunction();">...

case function is server-side: you may put parameters:
    <form action="/acount/?action=alert&param=value"... >
Then, on server, you question those parameters and execute the right function(s).

Comment: Could you please help me with this in detail. As to how do I handle it on server side. where do I put the function

Comment: On the default page in "account" (defined in form action) folder.